face detection with reactjs
I have simple react app which has three buttons one to start the camera feed, one to capture an image and displays it and one to detect face(s) in that image and add a box around the face with the dimensions.
'
import {useEffect} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const videoStyle = {
    'border': '1px solid black',
    'width': '650px',
    'height': '440px',
    'margin-right': '600px',
}

  const buttonStyle = {
    'border': '1px solid black',
    'width': '400px',
    'height': '40px',
    'margin-right': '600px',
  }

  const imageStyle = {
    'border': '1px solid black',
    'width': '650px',
    'height': '440px',
    'margin-right': '600px',
  }

  useEffect(() => {
  var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
  var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream
  var streaming = false;
  var video: any= null;
  var canvas: any= null;
  var photo: any= null;
  var startbutton = null;
  var detect = null;

  function startup() { 
      video = document.getElementById('video');
      canvas = document.getElementById('hidden');
      photo = document.getElementById('photo');
      startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');
      detect = document.getElementById("detect")
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
              video: true,
              audio: false
          })
          .then(function(stream) {
              video.srcObject = stream;
              video.play();
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
              alert("An error occurred: " + err);
          });
      video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
          if (!streaming) {
              height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
              if (isNaN(height)) {
                  height = width / (4 / 3);
              }
              video.setAttribute('width', width);
              video.setAttribute('height', height);
              canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
              canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
              streaming = true;
          }
      }, false);

      if (startbutton){
      startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
          takepicture();
          ev.preventDefault();
      }, false)};
      clearphoto();

      if (detect){
        detect.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            d()
            ev.preventDefault();
        }, false)};

  }
  function clearphoto() {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  }
  function takepicture() {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (width && height) {
          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = height;
          context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
          var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          photo.setAttribute('src', data);
      } else {
          clearphoto();
      }
  }
      window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
}, [])

  return (  
    <html>
        <body>
    <div className="contentarea">
      <button style={buttonStyle}>start </button>
    <div className="camera" draggable>
        <video id="video" style={videoStyle} ></video>
    </div>
    <div><button id="startbutton" style={buttonStyle}>Take photo</button></div>
    
    <canvas id="canvas" hidden></canvas>
    <div className="output">
        <img id="photo" style={imageStyle} alt="The screen capture will appear in this box."/> 
        <button id="detect" >Detect</button>
    </div>
    </div></body>
    </html>
)
  ;
}

export default App;


I've tried opencv.js but I'm not sure how to go about importing it, I was only able to find a link
"https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/opencv.js" but it still doesn't work inside the react app. With tensflow I keep getting error whenever I un/install any module such as "tensflow-models/face-landmarks-detection" or something like that. Problem is I'm only allowed to use the front-end for this, so I'm quite lost.

The above code is not very "React-y", and not very "modern JS":

use let or const and not var
use React constructs and not directly manipulating the DOM (.getElementById(), .addEventListener(), etc.)

Doing a search for "opencv react" on NPMJS I see a few hits that might be worth reviewing to get you up and running faster than trying to manually merge HTML instructions from the OpenCV website into a React app.
